# Add vertical(projection) line from point to categories, highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a areaspline plot(stacked), and what I need now is add a projection line from the toppest **point**(not chart) to the corresponding category. like: [image: what i want]

I lookup on the api reference about xAxis but did not find what I want.

Comment: Options demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGWjWW

Comment: It's not supported directly. You would have to either draw your own lines using the renderer() function, or set up a scatter or line series that would mimic the desired behavior.

Comment: OTOH, you could use the x axis gridlines, with a semitransparent white as the color:
http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/25bdLc1o/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines)

```
xAxis:{
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#ffffff',
                width: 2,
                value: 5.5
            }]
}
```

or [gridLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.gridLineColor)

```
xAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#fff'
},
```

Comment: But I only want it starts from the point, not the toppest of the chart.

Comment: why cannot you simply draw a line chart.

Comment: @strikers What you mean line chart? The designer needs areaspline chart, and s projection line from every point to the category.

Comment: @Jaskey what I mean is you are able to render the areaspline chart as required but the one that is hindering is the line projections. For rendering those line projections we can have a line chart as well (only for the line projections)

Comment: You can itearare on points, extract coordinates and print lines by [renderer.path](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path)